# Convert Java DH Public Key Generator to Node JS

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, public-key

I have a function like this:

```
public String generatePublicKeyEncoded() throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Serializable serializable = new SecureRandom();
    BigInteger bigInteger = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, (Random) serializable);
    serializable = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, (Random) serializable);
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(new DHParameterSpec(bigInteger, (BigInteger)serializable));
    this.keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    return HexEncoder.encode(this.keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
}
```

and I am trying to converto to node.
My node.js code is:

```
const prime_length = 1024;
const diffHell = crypto.createDiffieHellman(prime_length);
diffHell.generateKeys('base64');
const hexPublicKey = diffHell.getPublicKey('hex')
```

but my Java generated public key is

```
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
```

and node generated key is:

```
1b6254629d00a18333ec701558ef34b0df9b86569985799106c4d71d1fabd3c41ef25c7bf4a522498a92c983ca09e3435ebd09b51220d6ffccb296803f1718bf8cf7e0f72432b65b60d8a49d6d80fec6e708a88d2b00e2829e74534fa86a94d96a743725c6eb2076d5ac03edd909491639a359467a67fc64b9dc2fb420d822a2
```

Where is the error?

HexEncoder class:

```
public class HexEncoder {

    private static final byte[] a = { 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70 };

    public static String encode(byte[] paramArrayOfByte)
    {
        return encode(paramArrayOfByte, false, 0);
    }

public static String encode(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, boolean paramBoolean, int paramInt)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < paramArrayOfByte.length; i++)
        {
            if ((paramBoolean) && (i > 0) && (i % paramInt == 0)) {
                stringBuilder.append("\r\n");
            }
            int j = paramArrayOfByte[i];
            int k = j;
            if (j < 0) {
                k = j + 256;
            }
            j = k / 16;
            stringBuilder.append((char)a[j]);
            stringBuilder.append((char)a[(k % 16)]);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

---

Comment: where are you importing `HexEncoder` from?

Comment: This is a class.. sorry, I forgot to send in the question

Comment: I am not an expect on this, but the generated prime number is different in both the cases.

Comment: Why would the ever be the same? You are are generating the values randomly.

Comment: The problem is the size ... Java is much bigger than node, and I use this generated key to send as a body param to an endpoint .. and when i try do generate using node, it returns an error in the endpoint request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your Java generation of DH parameters is horribly wrong. The modulus (p) and generator (g) for DH are *not* simply large random primes. p must be a large prime, and does not need to be random, but MUST have a multiplicative group (Z<sub>p</sub><sup>*</sup>) with 'non-smooth' order, that is the order's prime factorization must not consist entirely of small factors, or more concretely the order must have a large prime factor. Because the order of the multiplicative group for prime p is p-1, this is commonly accomplished by choosing a safe prime (p=2q+1) or a Schnorr prime (p=kq+1) where q is a sufficiently large prime. OTOH g need not be large (and MUST not be larger than or equal to p, which can happen with your code) and need not be random but must generate a subgroup of sufficient size (usually q). Choosing parameters as you did will sometimes fail outright (key agreement won't work) but most of the time will simply be insecure -- the shared value that was supposed to be secret can easily be determined by an adversary and used to expose and/or alter your supposedly secure data. I wonder if you or someone confused DH with RSA (or, less likely, Rabin) which is/are quite different, even though they all involve large numbers and mathematics.

But that's offtopic for SO. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) and *numerous* Qs and As on security.SX and crypto.SX. For your actual question:

**It's the encoding.** For (all) Java `PublicKey` objects, `getEncoded()` returns [the 'SubjectPublicKeyInfo' format defined in X.509](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html) (and more conveniently repeated in RFC5280 aka PKIX, linked there) which is based on [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) and [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690). In particular it contains an OID identifying the algorithm as DH, a parameters structure containing p and g, and the actual public key value (commonly notated y) wrapped in a BITSTRING; for the value you posted:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -dump -inform d <64790186.bin
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 419 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 279 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :dhKeyAgreement
   19:d=2  hl=4 l= 264 cons:   SEQUENCE
   23:d=3  hl=3 l= 129 prim:    INTEGER           :DE4779E7F4523CA143FFE102853E671CAAAB96203B1FC3C42D0EA1CB6878FCA889C79C709DDB1190DF9073050B1AD410D34A48A6E5A1D2C1854C471528DB3C4FE48A237FC86BAA777AAB8A17750DBA7948F258BD55E480BA3FFD87076BC4B0429CE731E31A8320DC594F9BD5022CD203C95D73F5B3E91C930A0AF2FA7AEE1605
  155:d=3  hl=3 l= 129 prim:    INTEGER           :D719835971E8A91980141201FF765392A0049841142A3C203862AF8FFBC719528F142706639BD0C614EBA72660876F5A7011B5FC08224824577324FCF847648F24A600F408BED17770AAF958CC75076164DAA5E6179BFC573F40E2B086FC18A48B67A10F7B9B7C037A7BEEEDF554764CC8653C09AA3D330CC3C30F89616D8107
  287:d=1  hl=3 l= 133 prim:  BIT STRING
      0000 - 00 02 81 81 00 8e e0 27-b9 16 fc 87 be 26 27 cf   .......'.....&'.
      0010 - b5 3f 4d a7 66 93 a0 6e-ec ac 8d a2 a6 b9 15 5c   .?M.f..n.......\
      0020 - 66 d6 0b cd 99 77 a8 11-b3 73 2f 72 88 0b de 1a   f....w...s/r....
      0030 - a2 59 73 1f e3 7a d4 28-49 09 48 17 77 44 4f 7a   .Ys..z.(I.H.wDOz
      0040 - 3c 5b cf 7f 28 7a d5 f0-5b e4 5f 45 53 cc 06 d5   <[..(z..[._ES...
      0050 - 99 e7 e3 ba d6 73 6d 6b-ca 59 ea d8 b0 f6 c0 fe   .....smk.Y......
      0060 - 98 0f 47 13 04 ac 26 00-a6 77 a7 0c e4 6f 28 35   ..G...&..w...o(5
      0070 - fa 67 97 d1 8f aa 8a 23-75 73 91 6e 60 4a f4 0c   .g.....#us.n`J..
      0080 - a4 56 cc ee 1e                                    .V...
# if you know DER you can see the value in the BITSTRING is 
# the encoding of a 128-octet INTEGER, like the two in the parameters structure
```

nodejs `crypto`, although it actually uses OpenSSL internally which does support the X.509/PKIX SPKI format, does not use that format. It returns only the actual public key value (y). To create the same standard format as Java, do something like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function der(tag,val){ // for basic tags and up to 64kB, which are enough here
  var len = val.length;
  var enc = Buffer.alloc(4); enc[0]=tag;
  if( len < 128 ){ enc[1]=len; enc = enc.slice(0,2); }
  else if(len < 256 ){ enc[1]=0x81; enc[2]=len; enc = enc.slice(0,3); }
  else{ enc[1]=0x82; enc[2]=len>>8; enc[3]=len&0xFF; }
  return Buffer.concat([enc,val]);
}
function derpint(x){ return der(0x02, x[0]<128? x: Buffer.concat([onezero,x])); }
const onezero = Buffer.alloc(1,0);
function derseq(x){ return der(0x30, Buffer.concat(x)); }
const oidpkcs3 = Buffer.from('06092a864886f70d010301','hex');

var dh = crypto.createDiffieHellman(1024);
var pub = dh.generateKeys(); 
var p = dh.getPrime(), g = dh.getGenerator();

var algid = derseq([oidpkcs3,derseq([derpint(p),derpint(g)])]);
var spki = derseq([algid,der(0x03,Buffer.concat([onezero,derpint(pub)]))]);
console.log(spki.toString('hex'));
```

**(added)** although it wasn't in the question and Stack policy is that the question is supposed to be in the question, not a long discussion in comments, to be useful for *other* people:

for **private** keys Java similarly uses a generic format, but a *different* generic format as stated on that same Javadoc page for `Key`, namely PrivateKeyInfo from PKCS8 [more conveniently available as RFC5208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208#section-5). This has a version number, the same algid (OID+parameters) as SPKI, and the private value (notated x) wrapped in an OCTETSTRING instead of a BITSTRING, so replacing or adding to the last two lines above:

```
var prv = dh.getPrivateKey(); 
var pkcs8 = derseq([derpint(onezero),algid,der(0x04,derpint(prv))]);
console.log(pkcs8.toString('hex'));
```

Comment: Man, you are you are a genius. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I always thought that the correct DH-keygeneration on Java side is done with a "1024" or "2048" presented to the keygen. You are writing "Java generation of DH parameters is horribly wrong" but I searched for some hours now but didn't find any Java example that meets your thoughts regarding modulus & base (prime) generation. Can you kindly share  link to a "crptographic correct" solution? Thanks.

Comment: whats the meaning of "06092a864886f70d010301"?

Comment: @MichaelFehr: There are two parts to the generation process 1) generating the domain parameters g and p, just once, and 2) generating the private key and corresponding public key, everytime. dave_thompson was talking about #1 when he said that. You could let Java perform #1 using an AlgorithmParameterGenerator together with an DHGenParameterSpec, but OP is instead simply choosing two random primes.

Comment: In this solution, is there any way to get the PrivateKey? its just dh.getPrivateKey() ??

Comment: @MichaelFehr+ if you use `KeyPairGenerator/*forDH*/.initialize(int nbits, SecureRandom r)` it either uses predefined parameters for 'standard' sizes or else generates a Schnorr prime and generator (one option I mentioned) using the same logic defined for DSA in FIPS 186; see that. Or see https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/DHParametersHelper.java for the safe-prime method.

Comment: @gara: the value beginning 0609 is the encoded OID (aka Object Identifier) for DH, or more exactly PKCS3-type DH, which is the one used by most systems including Java. The encoding of OIDs in DER is complicated, and I didn't want to go through all the logic when you only need a single case. Yes, (nodejs crypto) dh.getPrivateKey is the private value (x) only; like the public key if a private key is externalized it usually has parameters and other info added, and here Java uses the PKCS8 standard which is similar in concept to the X.509 SPKI standard for public key.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I find out that if I write dh.getPublicKey(), the result is inserted in the spki variable... is this hex spki variable p + g + y, so that's the reason the hex string is bigger than dh.getPublicKey().toString('hex')' and publicKey is inside spki?         If I need to do the same with privateKey, what do I need to change in your node js example?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I need to use the private key in my code, but I tried to gererate it just changing your logic in this line: var spki = derseq([algid,der(0x03,Buffer.concat([onezero,derpint(pub)]))]);  , I changed "pub" to "dh.getPrivateKey()", but the privateKey generated was invalid to use in the next request .... What do I need to change?

Comment: @polonio: depends what you mean by '+'. SPKI for (PKCS3)DH _contains_ p,g,y but it isn't just _concatening_ p,g,y. For private, see my edit.